# CodeRush Extract class

Tags: .net, coderush

In coderush I can extract a method based on my code.

Is there a way to extract an entire class?

```
mycode  = 5

turns into

myclass= new myclass;
mycode = mymethod()
myclass
{
methods()
{
return mycode=5
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, there is such feature currently available in CodeRush